# Did an NFL team with the outright most Pro Bowlers miss the playoff before 2021?

Tags: trivia, nfl

In the 2021 NFL season the Indianapolis Colts had the most players (7) selected to the Pro Bowl (no other team had 7 Pro Bowl players), yet they missed the playoffs. Has this ever happened?

Answer (score 1):

> Did an NFL team with the outright most Pro Bowlers miss the playoff before 2021?

<strike>Yes.</strike> Edit - missed the word "outright."

The Steelers had [8 pro bowlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Pro_Bowl#Number_of_selections_per_team) but missed the playoffs during [the 2018 season](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/playoffs.htm).

Comment: Actually with the 7 team per conference playoffs that Steelers team would have made the postseason, but the Colts managed to miss even the extended field...